# Android: delete/hide player score from leaderboard

Tags: android, httprequest, google-play-games, leaderboard

There's a player that probably hacked my game on the Google Play Store and submitted an incredibly high score. I would like to hide that player from the leaderboard but to do so I only found this: https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/players/hide 
and no other explanations on how to use it. Calling those HTTP requests via browser obviously doesn't work because an authentication is needed.
What do I have to do to use those APIs to hide that player?

Answer (score 1):

For future strugglers as this is not well documented. You can hide players by adding a web application in your Google Play Console and using the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), to execute the REST APIs [Scores: list](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores/list) and [Players: hide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/management/api/players/hide) to get player ids and hiding her/him.

For a thorough walkthrough see my article: https://gaute.app/dev-blog/gpgs-hide-player

Answer (score 0):

You should `POST` to hide and `DELETE` to unhide. And you'll need a developer account. Everything is written in the doc

Comment: I think he is asking: Is there any GUI tool to simplify this?

Comment: @Gorcyn : Even if that is the case, if the OP is capable of writing an Android game in the first place, they should be able to put together a utility app to handle the leader board. After all, if the game is hackable they might have to do it regularly. Ideally they should fix the "back door" that allows the hack.

Comment: Yeah, then just use Curl to send the request.

Comment: @Squonk I think there should be a tool for that. Should everybody do his own tool to manage the same things that every game developer would manage, on their own?
I should add: Google Play Game Services are pretty easy to implement on the Android side, without any knowledge of complex HTTP API. Developing a "Game" is not that hard neither,.. (from what we can see on the Play Store)

Comment: @Gorcyn : If there *IS* a tool out there which could solve the OP's problem then the question is a bad fit for StackOverflow anyway and it should be closed as asking for off-site links / resources etc. Coming to SO and asking a question which has no specific programming content is off-topic. The OP should either develop their own tool to fix their specific problem or Google to see if there's an existing app (Android or browser based).